# Matrix Scale down using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, scaling

I have 254 * 128 integers and I need to scale down to 45 * 22,5 .

Could you please help me if I could perform with MATLAB.

Thanks
Baskar

Comment: What does `45*22,5` means

Comment: its just the size to be scaled

Comment: what is a `,` doing in size of a matrix. I understand that `45*22` is the size but what does `,5` means ? And if it is `45*22.5` then how is `number of columns ` in your matrix is a **DECIMAL**

Comment: I am aware its not possible for noninteger sized matrix, I was concerned over dimension for scaling.

Comment: @user3698732: How do you need to represent the matrix? If you need to keep it in RAM as an array, then Matlab (and probably most other programming languages) will not be able to help you, since you cannot have half-columns. If, instead, you're concerned about aspect ratio, why not scale to e.g. 450x225?

Comment: The 22.5 as length of a dimension is really unusual. Not only for Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot have non-integer sized matrices. 22,5 is not a valid dimension of a matrix.
2. If you are talking about images you can resize the matrix in Matlab using `imresize`.

.

```
 A = rand(254, 128);
 A = imresize(A, [45, 23]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,Is there any other way to scale 254 * 128 set of integers to the size of 45*22,5?

Thanks

Comment: @user3698732: please define what you mean with a size of 22.5. Also, what do you mean 'any other way'? In what way is this solution not working out for you?

Comment: @Jonas I am looking to scale down exactly to this size of 45 * 22,5
I am aware that I cannot have a non integer sized matrix so I am looking for exact scaling to this dimension other than using imresize.
Thanks

Comment: @user3698732, what you're asking for doesn't make any sense. How about scaling it to 450x225? Then you will at least have the dimensions matching.

Comment: @Robert Yea I agree to what you suggest but as you said I was concerned over dimension matching.